# Earpods remote control doesnt work with my iphone

Tags: iphone

I have an Earpods. It beautifully works with iPad (sound and remote control works perfect) but not with iPhone (only sound is correct, but nothing works with remote control). Anyone know why?

iPhone 6S, iOS 9.3.2

Comment: What is your iPad running on?

Comment: Does the microphone work?

Comment: iPad is running the same: `9.3.2`, it looks like microphone doesnt work also.